# BIOS Update Before Installing CPU

Tags: cpu, bios

I finally got around to builing a (shiny) new machine. So do I need to update BIOS before installing the new CPU?

New hardware components include,

Motherboard: ASUS H81M-PLUS

CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K

Comment: The specs says thay the board already has support for Intel Core i7 and other Intel CPUs. http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/H81MPLUS/specifications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CPU: **Core i7-4790K (4.0Ghz, 4C, HT, L3:8M, HD Graphic, 88W,
>   rev.C0)**
>
> Since PCB: **All**
>
> BIOS Revision: **2001**
>
> Note:
>   **Before using the new Intel 4th Gen Core processors, we suggest that you first download the BIOS updater for new Intel 4th Gen Core Processors and then update the BIOS using this tool.**

[Source](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H81MPLUS/HelpDesk_CPU/)

You will have to determine the current revision of the BIOS before you can determine if an update will be required.  You will need to contact ASUS Support to determine that information.